# How do I reverse a part (slice) of a list in Python?

Tags: python

Why doesn't this work?

```
# to reverse a part of the string in place 
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a[2:4] = reversed(a[2:4])  # This works!
a[2:4] = [0,0]             # This works too.
a[2:4].reverse()           # But this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`a[2:4]` creates a copy of the selected sublist, and this copy is reversed by `a[2:4].reverse()`.  This does not change the original list.  Slicing Python lists always creates copies -- you can use

```
b = a[:]
```

to copy the whole list.

Comment: @İsmail: I don't see a connection between mutability and the fact that slicing creates copies.  Slicing NumPy arrays does not create copies, and they are mutable as well.  These are independent design decisions.

Comment: @İsmail: I don't seem to understand what you are after.  If Python lists were immutable, you couldn't tell if a copy is created or not, because you can't alter it anyway.

Comment: Nit: "_Slicing Python lists always creates copies_"—except when they are assigned to, as in `a[2:4] = reversed(a[2:4])` in the OP's example. People may be led to think that `x = reversed(x)` and `x.reverse()` both modify `x`, but they are fundamentally different operations in Python, and their results differ when `x` is not a variable, as shown here.

Answer (score 63):

Just use the slice and reverse it.

```
a[2:4] = a[2:4][::-1]
```

Comment: Only drawback here is that it is not in-place i.e. it will use extra memory

Answer (score 15):

Another way you might consider is to use a reversed slice:

```
a[2:4] = a[3:1:-1]
```

Comment: While this does work, there's no way to use this exact method to reverse a slice containing the first element.

Comment: @quintopia It is, actually: just omit the first index: `assert a[3::-1] == [4, 3, 2, 1]`

Comment: @VMAtm good point. I know this now, but I didn't then. It does point to a certain lack of orthogonality in the language though, doesn't it?

Comment: For me it just a convention, that if you omit second (or first) index in spolyce, you simply say - from the beginning or till the end, no need to calculate those indexes.

Comment: I think this can be not used in a loop where the end index needs to reach all the start of the list.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it's worth further elaborating the reasons why

```
a[2:4].reverse()
```

does not seem to work.

In addition to the fact that `a[2:4]` creates a copy in the memory, it should be noted that

```
list.reverse()
```

reverses the list in place and its return type is `None`. If you do

```
print(a[2:4].reverse())
```

`None` is printed. Obviously, if you forcefully do,

```
a[2:4] = a[2:4].reverse()
```

Python would raise a `TypeError`. However, there does exist a copy of `a[2:4]` in the memory which has been reversed. It's just you have no reference to access it.

On the other hand, `a[2:4] = reversed(a[2:4])` works because `reversed()` returns a reverse iterator.

See comments of the accepted answer for how `a[2:4]` being different when appearing on the left of assignment.

Comment: great point actually , `arr[i:j].reverse()` return type is  `None`.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this purely in-place is with the good old loops:

```
def reverse(seq, start, stop):
    size = stop + start
    for i in range(start, (size + 1) // 2):
        j = size - i
        seq[i], seq[j] = seq[j], seq[i]


l = list(range(10))
print(l)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

reverse(l, 2, 5)
print(l)
# [0, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

a[2:4] is a copy of the list a that is built using the 2,3,4 items in list a. The first two work because you are assigning the changes into those spots in the original list. The last one doesn't work because you are not affecting the original list.

Answer (score 1):

> Here's a weird example and weirder solution using slicing and a bit of
>   list fundamentals.

***Problem:*** Reverse a list in parts of two.

**I/P :** [1,2,3,4,5,6]

**O/P:** [3,2,1,6,5,4]

**Soln:**

```
[item for i in range(0,len(l),len(l)/2) for item in l[i:i+len(l)/2][::-1]]
```

***Problem***: Reverse the letters of someones name.

E.g Harry Porter

O/p: yrraH retroP

**Soln:**

```
' '.join(map(lambda x:x[::-1], s.split()))
```

Answer (score 1):

To reverse an array from a particular index to another, please use this:

```
#start is the starting index
#end is the ending index
while start<end:
    nums[start],nums[end] = nums[end],nums[start]
    start+=1
    end-=1
```

All this does is that it picks one element from the start and one from the end and swaps them. Then it moves the start pointer front while the end pointer back.