# Slice function reverse - Python

Tags: python, file, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of tuples `d` of which I want a reversed slice:

```py
d = [('g', 5), ('f', 4), ('d', 3), ('s', 2), ('a', 1)]
```

Similarly to how `d[-3:]` outputs `[('d', 3), ('s', 2), ('a', 1)]`
I want a function that outputs this list but reversed, ie. `[('a', 1), ('s', 2), ('d', 3)]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reverse a part (slice) of a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647368/how-do-i-reverse-a-part-slice-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
d[-3:][::-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

A little more verbose, but without the additional copies of lists created by double-slicing:

```
from itertools import islice


list(islice(reversed(d), 3))
```

`reversed` produces an instance of `list_reverseitertor`, simple wraps the original list and produces its elements in reverse order when requested by the instance of `islice`, rather than creating a new reversed list to be subsequently sliced.

Answer (score 0):

```py
d[-1:-4:-1]
```

You can find this in details in the [slice documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice). Here we `start` from the end of the list, then proceed up to the `stop`, which is item of index `-4` (the first that is excluded) by `step`s of `-1`.