# Is there a way we can reverse a **portion** of a lisr **in-place** on **Python3** using a **built-in** function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, built-in, in-place

I understand that there are multiple ways to reverse a portion of a list in Python

#1

```
def reverse_list(a,b):
    while a<b:
        my_list[a], my_list[b] = my_list[b], my_list[a]
        a += 1; b -= 1 

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
reverse_list(2,4)

print(my_list)

Output:
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
```

#2

```
def reverse_list(my_list, a, b):
    return my_list[0:a] + my_list[a:b+1][::-1] + my_list[b+1:]

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(reverse_list(my_list, 2, 4))

Output:
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
```

#1 is in-place and #2 uses extra memory

So is there a way we can use a **built-in function** to do this **in-place**?
Python has reverse() function but that does not take **indices range(a,b)**.
Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reverse a part (slice) of a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647368/how-do-i-reverse-a-part-slice-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Hello, this is not in-place

Comment: The solution by Reman in the thread reverses in-place https://stackoverflow.com/a/40823118/14293552

Comment: You can do slice assignment too.

Comment: Thank you @jrmylow and Mark.
Would that be in-place?

Comment: Yes, slice assignment is in-place for lists.  It does not create a new list.